# Extracting part of the email address by using Python regular expression

Tags: python, regex, email

I have the following string:

```
'iamgood@yahoo.com, cc.a@est.gov.cn, j_193@ywuancjds.com, super.hard.bb@ililsa.bi'
```

I want to extract `com, gov, com, bi`.

I wrote `(?<=@)\w+` regex, but it turn out to extract `yahoo,est,ywuancjds,ililsa`. 
I don't know how to include the vocabulary behind `@`.

Comment: Regarding `est.gov.cn` -> `gov`. Do you want `a.b.c.d` to return only `c` then too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
re.findall(r'@[^\s.]+\.(\w+)', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VaVfDq/3/) and the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/vHbTo4)

**Details**

- `@` - a `@` char
- `[^\s.]+` - 1 or more chars other than whitespace and a dot
- `\.` - a dot
- `(\w+)` - Group 1 (the value captured in this group will only be returned by `re.findall`): one or more word chars.

Python demo snippet:

```
import re
text = "iamgood@yahoo.com, cc.a@est.gov.cn, j_193@ywuancjds.com, super.hard.bb@ililsa.bi"
print( re.findall(r"@[^\s.]+\.(\w+)", text) )
# => ['com', 'gov', 'com', 'bi']
```

Comment: I am also wondering if I only want the email address in odd order, how could I write it?

Comment: @user13196723 Sorry, not sure what you mean.